# Where can I find a 3.5mm female receiver?

Tags: headphones, cable

I have some headphones with a super long cord, and I want to shorten the cord. So, I need two things. I need a male plug to add to the short cord after cutting in down to size. But, I don't want to just throw away the rest of the cord, so I want to turn it into an extension cord. To do this, I need a female receiver for the cord. The setup I'm thinking of doing is this:

[image: headphones]

Answer (score 3):

Radio Shack sells male and female audio connectors in a variety of sizes/formats, including the 3.5 mm type. Take care with your soldering to minimize the effect on sound quality.

Comment: No they don't. At least not online, and there isn't a store near me. http://www.radioshack.com/search?q=3.5+mm#q=3.5%20mm&sz=58

Comment: Imperial, not metric: http://www.radioshack.com/1-8-stereo-in-line-audio-jack/2740274.html#.VHUzR4siWws